# Recursion functions for factorial

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I am writing this code to get the 10! ,however, I believe I have an infinite loop in there since it keeps repeating the same error code. I am trying to find the issue but can not seem to.

```
def calculatingfactor(num2cal):
  """this fuction will be calculating a mathematical factorial"""
  if num2cal == 1:
    returnvalue = 1
  elif num2cal <= 0:
    returnvalue = 0
  else:
    print("Calculating the facterial of {}".format(num2cal))
    variable2 = calculatingfactor(num2cal - 1)
    returnvalue = calculatingfactor(num2cal*variable2)
    return 

#main code
first_fact=calculatingfactor(10)
print (first_fact)
```

Comment: I see that you have a good understanding of the factorial, however: why are you calling the recursive function twice? That second call will never end making you get a "StackOverflowException". You should update the 10th line of code for -> returnvalue *= variable2. Also note that the condition "elif num2cal <= 0" will make your result 0. Consider reviewing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recursive case of your code looks incorrect to me.  You should be calling the same function with `num2cal` decremented by one, then returning the current value multiplied by whatever that recursive call returned.

```
def calculatingfactor(num2cal):
  if num2cal == 1:
    return 1
  elif num2cal <= 0:
    return 0
  else:
    print("Calculating the facterial of {}".format(num2cal))
    variable2 = calculatingfactor(num2cal - 1)
    return num2cal*variable2 

# main code
first_fact=calculatingfactor(10)
print (first_fact)
```

Comment: I did try that Tim, I still unfortunately get the same error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType' and the error prints out about 20 times

Comment: @JoanthanMaldonado The above code [is working in this demo](https://rextester.com/IYAHVV68548).  You must have some other problem in your code.

Comment: You were correct with your edit and it was just an error on my end. Thank you !